# In the onSubmit event, how to pass the TextField Value without any value passed by the form React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am new to react js and react hook.
I have three text fields in my form.
Ex: First Text Field value=5
Second Text Field value=3

Third Text Field value=FirstTextField-SecondTextField.

The first Text field value is the default value. But the second text field is editable. When I change the text field value. It's automatically updated to (based on calculation) text field third.

```
    const formvalues = useForm({
        mode: 'onSubmit',
        reValidateMode: 'onChange',
        defaultValues: {
        workhrs:0,
        remainhrs:0,
        actualhrs:5
        },
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
      });
      const { control, watch, reset, handleSubmit, onChange, formState, getValues } = methods;
    
    const [workhrsvalue, setWorkhrsValue]=useState();
    const [remainhrsvalue, setRemainhrsValue]=useState();
    const handleTextChanged = (e) => {
            var NewValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);
            setWorkhrsValue(NewValue);
            var remaininghrsValue=(parseFloat(actualhrs)-parseFloat(workhrs));
            setRemainhrsValue(remaininghrsValue);
          }
    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    <FormProvider {...formvalues}>
            <form
              noValidate
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="flex flex-col md:overflow-hidden"
            >
    <Controller
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...field}
                                    id="actualhrs"
                                    autoFocus={true}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    placeholder="actualhrs"
                                />
                            )}
                            name="actualhrs"
                            defaultValue="5"
                            control={control}
                        />
    <Controller
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...field}
                                    id="workhrs"
                                    autoFocus={true}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    placeholder="workhrs"
                                    onChange={e => {
                                        handleTextChanged(e)
                                        field.onChange(e)
                                      }}
                                />
                            )}
                            name="workhrs"
                            defaultValue=""
                            control={control}
                        />
                    <Controller
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...field}
                                    id="remainhrs"
                                    autoFocus={true}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    placeholder="remainhrs"
                                />
                            )}
                            name="remainhrs"
                            defaultValue=""
                            control={control}
                        />
                        </form>
                        </FormProvider>
```

> [ExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kHDS.png)

I need to pass the Textfield3(remainhrs) value to submit event. But remainhrs value always coming undefined. How to resolve that.

Comment: Since you only update the third field when the second field is updated, why not call the relevant function from the onChange of the second field? You should already have all the relevant information when the second field's onChange is called.

Comment: oh. How to do this? Give me an example.